# How to manually modify model parameters?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

```
local_model.bn1.num_batches_tracked.fill_(0.)

local_model.layer1.0.bn1.num_batches_tracked.fill_(0.)

local_model.layer1.0.bn2.num_batches_tracked.fill_(0.)
```

I want to modify some model parameters to zero. The first line works fine but the second line onwards. I will get the following syntax error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`:

[image]

Is there a better to do this? For example, can the parameters' name containing `num_batches_tracked` be modified to 0?

Comment: I looked at documentation for a second, and it looks like the neural network is saved to a file. Can you edit the file before loading it? and the period `.` is used to access an object's variables or members / fields / properties. The error comes from `local_model.layer1.0` python tries to access variable named 0, or the number 1.0 out of nowhere in the middle of the name `local_model.layer.bn1.num_batches_tracked`.

Comment: also try printing `dir()` `dir('__name__')` `dir(local_model)`

Comment: this is my first time touching machine learning-related programming. The model seems to be pre-trained from 'https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet18-5c106cde.pth' and used directly. So I'm not sure how to edit the file before loading it. is there another way to go around this?

Comment: I think I've tracked it down to a [potential interceptable spot](https://github.com/ebagdasa/backdoors101/blob/003961b04ccb0c84c3295f9164b2369d6712ac28/tasks/fl/fl_task.py#L28) where the local model is created. Follow it up or down stream untill you find your interface to it. Click colored text on github to see references and the search bar is also really powerful inside repositories

Comment: any idea where to go from [here](https://github.com/ebagdasa/backdoors101/blob/70869e5030eb282bb40161c58aa2f0fdf165d73b/models/resnet_cifar.py#L126:~:text=resnet18(pretrained%3DNone%2C%20num_classes%3DNone%2C%20bn_enable%3DTrue)%3A)

Comment: where did you get this path name from? In python you **cannot** have attributes that are numbers. And this is where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

After loading your model you can use this function to do what you want.

```
def reset_tracked_batches_num(model:torch.nn.Module, constant=0.0):
    def recurs(model):
        for layer in model.children():
            if hasattr(layer, 'num_batches_tracked'):
                torch.nn.init.constant_(layer.num_batches_tracked,constant)
                #print(layer.num_batches_tracked)
            recurs(layer)
    recurs(model)
```

Example:

```
model = resnet18()
reset_tracked_batches_num(model, 5)
```